# Pandas dataframe [] issue

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to python. Could someone help me why the first code statement generates no coding error but the second one will generate a keyerror(I do not even know what is a keyerror).

p.s.: data is a DataFrame,'StrategyCumulativePct' and 'BuyHold' are two columns in the DataFrame respectively.

```
data[['StrategyCumulativePct', 'BuyHold']].plot()

data['StrategyCumulativePct', 'BuyHold'].plot()
```

On the other hand, may I ask why sometimes when I had only written 20 lines of codes but there could be errors pointing an arrow at lines 2000 / 3000.... which I have not created before? Thanks.

Comment: The single square bracket with output a Pandas Series, while a double square bracket will output a Pandas DataFrame.  The interior brackets are for list, and the outside brackets are indexing operator. Means, you must use double square brackets if you select two or more columns.

Comment: Thank you Vishwas. But when I have not understood the above logics from you, how should I check the errors by myself and get the answer? Would you mind to suggest me some ways please? Thanks.